Contour plot with 4 variables
I have below contour plot using ggplot package
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

f <- function(x, y) { r <- sqrt(x^2+y^2+8^2+8^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }

x = y = seq(-10, 10, length.out = 30)
z = cbind(data.frame(x), as.data.frame(outer(x, y, f))
names(z) = c('x', as.character(y))

z1 = melt(z, id.vars = 'x')
names(z1) = c('x', 'y', 'z')
z1$y = as.numeric(as.character(z1$y))

ggplot(z1, aes(x, y, z = z)) + geom_contour() + geom_contour_filled()

While this is fine with only 2 independent variables i.e x and y, I actually have a function with 4 variables like below
f <- function(x, y, p, q) { r <- sqrt(x^2+y^2+p^2+q^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }

Could you guide me if there is any way to draw contour plot for above function?

This isn't a programming question, it's a question about statistical graphics.

I believe otherwise. It is indeed a programming question how to program one certain plot using R. Could you please elaborate what exactly you define as programming question? I believe a programming question is the one how to create a computer program to solve certain problem. Creating a plot definitely belong to solving certain problem

But what kind of plot do you want to create?  Your question looks more like "I have some data.  How should I plot it?"  Show us an example of the plot that you find online, and someone can answer the programming question of how to create it in R.

Short answer is surely No. A contour plot shows how one variable varies w.r.t. two others. Perhaps a series of contour plots.

Strictly speaking, such a "contour plot" would be a collection of three-dimensional hypersurfaces in four dimensions. That can't be displayed in this universe, so presumably you don't literally mean "contour plot." Could you explain what you do mean?
